# Pyqt5, Class function won't change label text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

If u need the ui itself just comment it and I'll send it to you directly

```
class Users:
    def __init__(self, name, birth, location, password):
        self.name = name
        self.birth = birth
        self.location = location
        self.password = password

    def printInfo(self):
        self.name.setText(self.name)
        self.birth.setText(self.birth)
        self.location.setText(self.location)


userDict = dict()
userDict["Jeff"] = Users("Jeff", "Something", "Something", "12345")


# Class Window For Start Screen
class Start(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        loadUi("start.ui", self)  # Load Pyqt5 Designer Ui and Objects
        self.setFixedWidth(588)
        self.setFixedHeight(400)
        self.startButton.clicked.connect(self.pressStart)

    @staticmethod
    def pressStart():
        stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(1)


# Class Window for startGame
class startGame(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(startGame, self).__init__()
        loadUi("game_start.ui", self)  # Load PyQt5 Designer Ui and Objects
        self.setFixedWidth(588)
        self.setFixedHeight(400)
        self.menuButt.clicked.connect(self.pressMenu)
        self.input.returnPressed.connect(self.find)
        self.findData.clicked.connect(self.find)

    def find(self):
        if self.input.text() in userDict.keys():
            userDict[self.input.text()].printInfo()

        else:
            noData()

    @staticmethod
    def pressMenu():
        stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)


def noData():
    warning = QMessageBox()
    warning.setWindowTitle("Warning")
    warning.setText("No Data Found")
    warning.exec_()



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = Start()
game = startGame()
stackedWidget = QStackedWidget()  
stackedWidget.addWidget(mainWin) 
stackedWidget.addWidget(game) 
stackedWidget.show() 
app.exec()
```

I'm using Pycharm and there's no error showing. But when I enter "Jeff" and hit enter (or find) a popup shows up saying "Python has stopped working. A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

I'm Guessing that the problem is in this line

```
def printInfo(self):
     self.name.setText(self.name)
     self.birth.setText(self.birth)
     self.location.setText(self.location)
```

or

```
userDict[self.input.text()].printInfo()
```

because when I change one or both to "print("Hi")" it works.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Yes, the problem is there, `self` is an instance `Users`, and all of those name, birth, location and password are strings, and don't have any `setText` attribute. Since you didn't provide an UI to work with, it's a bit hard to give you an actual answer, but I'll give you a hint anyway: your `Users` class is used as a data container, and as such it should not be able to directly modify another object; what you could do is to create a method that *returns* its fields, call that method in `find` (if the key exists) and set the values from there.

Comment: Also, you should *not* access global variables from an instance like you're doing for `stackedWidget`. I know that this is only an example, but there are very rare cases for which doing something like that is a good idea, and it should only be done when you really know what you're doing, especially considering that you're trying to access a parent object.

Comment: you used `self.name` as a string and a label widget. it can not be both. if you upload your ui code we can help more. and try always to put your code in a minimal way but reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks To musicamate. He said "class is used as a data container, and as such it should not be able to directly modify another object" - "create a method that returns its fields"

So I did what he said and made return functions for my class.
And with a lot of thinking I coded this.

```
self.name.setText(userDict[self.input.text()].returnName())
self.birth.setText(userDict[self.input.text()].returnBirth())
self.location.setText(userDict[self.input.text()].returnLocation())
```

Thanks so much to him. I don't know how much I could credit him other than mentioning his name.

Comment: Mention is fine enough, as long as you type the name correctly ;-)